# Problems with a SQL statement including a WHERE, AND, OR clause codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am having trouble figuring out how to fix this query.

Here is my CodeIgniter code

```
    return $this->db
        ->select('vehVin, vehMake, vehModel, seller, dealership, buyer, logistics.warehouseName, transportDate, car_tracking.keys, car_tracking.window')
        ->where('transportDate <', $yesterday)
        ->where('(car_tracking.keys', "'0'", FALSE)
        ->or_where("car_tracking.stickers = '0')", NULL, FALSE)
        ->join('logistics',  'logistics.stockid = vehicles.stockid')
        ->join('car_tracking',  'car_tracking.stockid = logistics.stockid')
        ->get('vehicles')
        ->result();
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
Unknown column 'car_tracking.stickers' in 'where clause'

`SELECT `vehVin`, `vehMake`, `vehModel`, `seller`, `dealership`, `buyer`, `logistics`.`warehouseName`, `transportDate`, `car_tracking`.`keys`, `car_tracking`.`window`
 FROM (`vehicles`) 
 JOIN `logistics` ON `logistics`.`stockid` = `vehicles`.`stockid` 
 JOIN `car_tracking` ON `car_tracking`.`stockid` = `logistics`.`stockid` 
 WHERE `transportDate` < '2013-11-25' 
 AND (car_tracking.keys = '0' OR car_tracking.stickers = '0')`
```

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure car_tracking.stickers exists.
I would also consider putting the sql query raw. because codeigniter's query builder has a lot of issues. It cannot handle most of query conditions when they are used together.